# Html-Agility-Pack not loading the page with full content?

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, scrape

i am using Html Agility Pack to fetch data from website(scrapping)

My problem is the website from i am fetching the data is load some of the content after few seconds of page load.

SO whenever i am trying to read the particular data from particular Div its giving me null.

but in `var page` i just not getting the division `reviewBox`..becuase its not loaded yet.

```
public void FetchAllLinks(String Url)
{
    Url = "http://www.tripadvisor.com/";
    HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(Url);

    var link_list= page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='reviewBox']");

    foreach (var link in link_list)
    {
        htmlpage.InnerHtml = link.InnerHtml;
    }
}
```

so can anyone please tell me how to delay the request that

```
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(Url);
```

will load the full data in `page` varibale

Answer (score 3):

It's not about delaying the request. That node is populated by javascript using the DOM and the Html Agility Pack is the wrong tool for that requirement (it isn't a web engine at all, it only loads the base Html).

When I need to get at stuff that requires a full web engine to parse, I typically use **WatiN**. It's designed to help unit test actual web pages, but that means it allows programmatic access to web pages through a given browser engine and will load the full document. It comes with IE or Firefox drivers out of the box and I vaguely recall that Chrome wasn't hard to use, either.

Comment: "Works with Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9 and FireFox 2 and 3"