# Getting content from web page, that is populated through a javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse a web page using Html Agility Pack, what I have understod from my attempts is that the web page is "populated" using a javascript. When I load the page using

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(linkToPage);
```

I get an empty page. The page is a sub page so to say, and I'm using the original page to scrap the links to these sub pages (it works for the main page since this one does not used javascript to populate the page, I assume).

Is there a way to parse a web page that populates through javascript, or is there a better tool for this?

Comment: related question : [Html-Agility-Pack not loading the page with full content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955793/html-agility-pack-not-loading-the-page-with-full-content)

Comment: Yes it is related but there has got to be another way than using a tool used, intentionally, for testing?

Answer (score -1):

See this if you wish to use JAVA, I worked with  [FTL](http://freemarker.org/) and also [JSrender](http://www.jsviews.com/), both were pretty cool

Comment: Thanks but the intention is to use .net.