# Scraping using Html Agility Package

Tags: html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape data from a news article using HtmlAgilityPackage the      link is as follows http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/vyapam-scam-documents-show-chief-minister-shivraj-chouhan-delayed-probe-780528

I have written the following code below to extract all the comments in this articles but for some reason my variable aTags is returning null value

Code:

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(txtinputurl.Text);
        var aTags =    document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='com_user_text']");
        int counter = 1;
        if (aTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var aTag in aTags)
            {
                lbloutput.Text += lbloutput.Text + ". " + aTag.InnerHtml + "\t" + "<br />";
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

I have also used this XPath but still the same result //div[@class='newcomment_list']/ul/li/div[@class='headerwrap']/div[@class='com_user_text']
Please help me with the correct Xpath to Extract all the comments 
Searched all over the net but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do a 'View Source' on the page and search for `com_user_text`. The user comments don't appear at all. They are loaded via javascript after the page is loaded. So when you load the page content via `getHtmlWeb.Load()`, you don't get user comments.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985856/423105) says, HTML Agility is not a tool capable of emulating a browser and running javascript. Instead, you need something like [WatiN](http://watin.org)  that "allows programmatic access to web pages through a given browser engine and will load the full document."

Comment: P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to have posted this question twice... was that intentional?

Comment: Sir you mean to say i wont be able to complete the task using HtmlAgilityPackage...and you advise me to use WaitN is this similar to HAP

Comment: @user3818862: It is similar, except that instead of simply parsing HTML into a tree structure and letting you select nodes from it (as HAP does), Watir/WatiN drives an actual web browser, which does much more... including, running Javascript, so that you can test dynamic pages.

Comment: Hi Sir Hi @LarsH just wanted to know..is it possible to scrape content from the webpage after the javascript is loaded completely using Html Agility Pack

Comment: @user3818862: No, I don't think so. HAP merely fetches the HTML, parses it into a tree structure, and lets you select nodes from it, e.g. using XPath. It does not run Javascript code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11394830/423105 for more info.